# How to set Secure Cookie on WSGI applications in python

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

How to set Secure Cookie on WSGI applications in python
With Secure Cookie I mean one that can be read on only https

Answer (score 6):

The `Response.set_cookie` function accepts an optional `secure` parameter. Example:

```
>>> res.set_cookie('key', 'value', max_age=360, path='/',
...                domain='example.org', secure=True)
>>> res.headers['Set-Cookie']
'key=value; Domain=example.org; Max-Age=360; Path=/; expires=... GMT; secure'
```

You can use `secure=True` in case you use HTTPS.

See [here](http://docs.webob.org/en/latest/reference.html#id5) for more details.